Why PATCH Method Fails While POST Method Works in Laravel?
I am encountering an issue when sending a PATCH request in my Laravel application. When sending a PATCH request to update a resource, I am not getting the expected result. However, when I send the same request using the POST method, I get the desired result. What could be the issue with the PATCH request?
// web
Route::patch('{id}/update', [UrunlerController::class, 'update'])->name('magaza.urun.guncelle.submit');

// Controller
    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        $sayi = $request->input('sayi');

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'sayi' => $sayi
        ]);
    }

// vanilla js
document.getElementById('patates').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('sayi', 123); // Basit veri ekliyoruz

    var url = `{{ route('magaza.urun.guncelle.submit', ['id' => 8]) }}`; 

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        body: formData 
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Hata:', error);
    });
});

The result I expected
{
    "success": true,
    "sayi": "123"
}

The result I encountered
{
    "success": true,
    "sayi": null
}

Laravel v:11.20.0

A 500 error can be a lot of things, take a look at storage/logs and find out what the actual error is.

But then if you're getting a 500 error, how are you also getting the {     "success": true,     "sayi": null } response at the same time? If the code crashed such that it caused a 500, I don't see how it could get as far as returning the response. I could be wrong but the information you've provided appears to be contradictory.

Sorry for asking the wrong question, I will correct it immediately.

@ADyson  fetch will actually allow you to get a response from a 500 status code, or any status code for that matter.   The OP is not doing a if (!response.ok) { throw check so in theory it can happen.   It might make sense if the OP does this check to take it out of the equation.

You have to prevent browser’s default behavior invoked by click method. Pass an event object to the callback function and put event.preventDefault() at first function’s line.

@Keith sure, but my point was that if the PHP code had crashed (which is usually why a 500 error occurs on the server), it probably wouldn't have got as far as outputting any JSON at all. I'm not talking about how it's handled on the client-side.
